# How to find second highest cost in mysql using top 2 ties with

Tags: sql, sql-server

trying to get second highest part cost.

what I have:

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES PartNbr, Description
FROM PART 
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT TOP 2 WITH TIES PartNbr
      FROM PART
      ORDER BY Cost DESC) 
ORDER BY Cost ASC;
GO
```

the data:

```
  [PART](
  [PartNbr] [numeric](18, 0) NULL,
  [Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
  [Cost] [numeric](18, 2) NULL,
  [SalesPrice] [numeric](18, 2) NULL
```

Im trying to get back the PartNbr and The description that has the second highest cost. I can only seem to get back the lowest costing PartNbr.

Comment: You wrote "mysql" but tagged sql server. Pick the correct one and stick with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the following code will give you what you are looking for

`SELECT partNbr, Description 
FROM PART a
WHERE 2 = (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cost) FROM PART b 
WHERE a.cost<=b.cost)`

Answer (score 0):

`ROW_NUMBER()` will make this much easier:

```
SELECT PartNbr, Description
FROM (SELECT PartNbr, 
             Description, 
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COST DESC) RN
      FROM Part) P
WHERE RN = 2
```

This works by assigning a row number based on cost, then selecting the row with the 2nd highest cost (`RN = 2`)

Another way, closer to what you have, would be:

```
SELECT TOP 1 PartNbr, Description
FROM Part
WHERE Cost IN (SELECT TOP 2 Cost
               FROM Part
               ORDER BY Cost DESC)
ORDER BY Cost ASC
```

But that seems rather confusing to me.  I would stick to the first option since it's easily scaled to other costs (`RN = 18` if you want the 18th highest cost part, etc.)